# Adding extra html to the assertion report of QUnit test

Tags: qunit

I would like to add a chart to the assertion report of a QUnit test. If the test fails this makes it easier to debug.

How can I insert extra html to the QUnit report from within the test?

I want the chart to be in the collapsable report of the test so I can add a chart for each test and I don't need to see it when the test passes.

Answer (score 0):

Wauw karel, that's a damn good question!

Open up qunit.js

after your if(tests) give an extra assertion.jQuery allong in your for loop

that should do it